# Selected input value not reflecting in JS controller of LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning, javascript, html, lightning-events

I am trying to create LWC component with HTML markup as below. The selected input values are not reaching JS controller. Tried multiple ways but the value is showing as null. Below is the code. What I might be doing wrong ?

HTML

```
   <div >
      <lightning-input type="date" name="startDate" requried="true" label="Start Date" value={startDate}></lightning-input>
    </div>
    <div >
      <lightning-input type="date" name="endDate" requried="true" label="End Date" value={endDate}></lightning-input>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div >
          <button class="slds-button slds-button_brand" onclick={download}>Download </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

JS

```
import { LightningElement, api, track } from "lwc";


export default class downloadInp extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    
    
    @api
    startDate = null;

    @api
    endDate = null;

    
 download(event) {
     
        var startDate = this.startDate;
        var endDate = this.endDate;

        console.log('startDate = '+startDate+' this.startDate -- '+this.startDate);
        console.log('endDate = '+endDate);
        
        
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LWC does not do automatic round-trip synchronization between the "view" (the screen) and the "model" (your JavaScript properties). You have to explicitly define handlers to receive the changes, generally via the `onchange` event handler, for each input. This can be found in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/events_handling) under "Listen for Changes to Input Fields".

Update your template to add the handler:

```html
<lightning-input type="date"
    name="startDate"
    required="true"
    label="Start Date"
    value={startDate}
    onchange={handleStartChange}>
</lightning-input>
```

Update your JavaScript to add the handler:

```js
handleStartChange(event) {
    this.startDate = event.target.value;
}
```

Obviously you need to do this for both inputs.

Note that you may have issues with trying to update `@api` annotated properties from within your component. You might need to switch to using [getters and setters](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.js_props_getters_setters) to enable this.